# Painted Epiphone V tailpiece

Tags: electric-guitar, electronics

I recently bought a 2nd hand Epiphone V. The tailpiece was rusted and badly damaged.
I tried finding a replacement part, but couldn't find in locally (South Africa). Even after importing one from Amazon, it wasn't exactly the same size.

Without thinking it through, I spray painted the tail piece. It now looks great, but this morning I realized that there's a grounding wire touching the tailpiece, which probably means it needs to be conductive, that I have now prevented.

Am I in trouble?

Comment: Does it sound ok when you play it? If yes, then it’s ok

Comment: If there's no hum or buzz when touching/not touching the strings, when it's played through the amp, it'll be fine. If there is a difference, it's telling you that the wire is needed. Not a clue what the electricity system does in S.A.

Comment: I haven't actually wired it up yet, so I have no idea if there's a buzz. Didn't want to wire it up if there was no chance of it being a problem.

Comment: Is the tailpiece the flat triangular delta shape type? I see some with a stop tailpiece.

Answer (score 3):

You might as well scape a bit of paint/rust off from the underneath, and perhaps lengthen the wire to reach it, then solder or otherwise fix it to the tailpiece. Maybe it won't make any difference but if it's an easy job, do it properly.

Comment: I also thought about doing that, but where I think it's going to be a problem is where the string get surface contact with the piece, is on the "eye"/hole. I can possible just try to get in there with a file to get it off, but yes, I think this is going to be my plan A if it doesn't work.